# If $K/k$ is finite, is $K[[T]]$ algebraic over $k[[T]]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $K/k$ be a finite extension of fields, is $K[[T]]$ algebraic over $k[[T]]$?

I think the compositum $Kk[[T]]$ is algebraic over $k[[T]]$, but not sure about $K[[T]]/Kk[[T]]$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $(\alpha_i)_{i\in I}$ be a basis of $K$ over $k$.

Choose any $f=\sum_{n\geq k}\beta_n T^n\in K((T))$. Now, you can write each $\beta_n$ as $\sum_{i\in I}\alpha_ic_{i,n}$ (this is a finite sum) for some $c_{i,n}\in k$. Then 
$$f=\sum_{n\geq k}\sum_{i\in I} \alpha_ic_{i,n}T^n=\sum_{i\in I}\alpha_i\sum_{n\geq k}c_{n,i}T^n.$$

Since each $\alpha_i$ is algebraic over $k$, it is also algebraic over $k((T))$. Since $I$ is finite, it follows that $f$ is algebraic over $k((T))$.

Comment: Ok, thanks! The original question I had in mind was about $k^{sep}[[T]]/k[[T]]$, your answer also illustrates that!

Comment: @Qixiao: I'm not sure: $k^{\textrm{sep}}/k$ may be infinite. In this case, I believe that $k^{\textrm sep}((T))/k((T)$ is not algebraic, but rather, there is a dense subfield of $k^{\textrm {sep}}((T))$ algebraic over $k((T))$. In other words, $k^{\textrm {sep}}((T))$ is the completion of the separable closure of $k((T))$.

Comment: Yes, that's what I understood from your previous comment, $k^{sep}[[T]]/k[[T]]$ may not be algebraic, but for finite extension, we have $Kk[[T]]=K[[T]]$, thanks!

Comment: @Qixiao: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is yes.
It is enough to prove this when the extension is simple, i.e. $K=k(\alpha)$ for some $\alpha$. Then $K[[T]]=k(\alpha)[[T]]=k[[T]](\alpha)$, so it is a finite extension of $k[[T]]$.

Comment: Sorry, I think the elements of K[[T]]K[[T]] is given by an infinite sequence (ai)i(ai)i in KK, and usually such a sequence is not a finite sum of sequence (bi)i(bi)i with bi∈kbi∈k. – Qixiao just now   edit

Comment: I don't think you understood what I meant. If $f(t)=a_0+a_1t+a_2t^2+...\in K[[T]]$ is a series, and $K=k(\alpha)$, you can write each $a_i$ as a polynomial in $\alpha$ over $k$, and then break the coefficients of each $t^i$ in order to write $f(t)$ as a polynomial in $\alpha$ over $k[[T]]$.

Comment: You are right, sorry I didn't understand your point just now..

Comment: Your argument also shows when $K/k$ is finite, then $Kk[[T]]=K[[T]]$.